# Windows 10 search can't find a file

Tags: windows-10, search

Can somebody explain me please why Windows 10 can't find the file which surely exists on the disc?

Web applications can make really complex fulltext search BUT Windows is not able to find a file. It really annoys me.

Look at the screenshot. What the hell is it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It’s a file in a dot-folder. I would expect Windows to not index it.

Comment: Yes it is dot folder. But as I see it is not able to find also png files in common folders. I added screenshot to question with another search.

Comment: Go to the top level folder in Windows Explorer and search from the top right search bar. That works for files not indexed.

Comment: It does not work for the first example. Second works. But this is not what I want. I want to force Windows to work properly like in 21 century.

Comment: rebuild the search index.